# CodeBlocks: UIAutomation.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, codeblocks, ui-automation

I am trying to include the `UIAutomation.h` library in my `Code::Blocks` client but I think I am doing something wrong. I just typed:

```
#include <UIAutomation.h>
```

at top of my program where all my other headers are and I get this error message right away when I compile:

> fatal error: UIAutomation.h: No such file or directory

I am a bit of a newb with these things, and I saw some people talk online about a "linker". If a linker has anything to do with me being able to use the `UI Automation library`, please let me know what is a linker and how do I use it? Otherwise, please let me know what you think I could be doing wrong.

Comment: Is `UIAutomation.h` in the same folder as all your other headers? Otherwise use a full path or step back to a more explicit path such as `#include "Folder\Folder\Folder\UIAutomation.h"`

Comment: **Also:** Please don't repost questions over and over again! Improve your existing ones by editing as asked for, or delete your old question before posting it again.

Comment: You are probably missing to setup some include and library pathes for your local environment with your projects compiler/linker options.

Comment: sorry about that bro, I thought I had to remake them, I will make sure to delete my previous post

Comment: @Cyber ohh ok so I can do like #include "c:\programfiles\...\UIAutomation.h"??.. do I have to include the <>? like: #include <"c:\blah\blah"> or #include "c:\blah\blah"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ohh ok so I can do like `#include "c:\programfiles\...\UIAutomation.h"`??.. do I have to include the <>? like: `#include <"c:\blah\blah"> or #include "c:\blah\blah"`??

Yes you can do that, but that's very probably a bad idea!

You should better use the `-I` option of the actual compiler to specify where to search for additional (besides standard) include files:

```
-I"c:\programfiles\UIAutomation\include"
```

Also you'll need to set the `-L` option for the linker to specify where to find the corresponding libraries for `UIAutomation`:

```
-L"c:\programfiles\UIAutomation\lib"
```

and the library itself with the `-l<lib>` option:

```
-lUIAutomation
```

The latter name depends which library files are actually present in the directory specifed with the `-L` option. The above sample expects to find a file named `libUIAutomation.a` or `libUIAutomation.lib` there.

I'm not really experienced with the [codeblocks](/questions/tagged/codeblocks) IDE, but from what I remember it allows you to set these options in the project settings.

**NOTE:**
All the specific option references given above, refer to the actual toolchain used for your codeblocks project. These will apply for the most commonly used toolchains (e.g. like GCC), but may vary for different ones. Though, there- will be certainly equivalent options for the compiler and linker tool used.

Comment: AWSOME answer, thanks man. That saves a lot of time lol. I am still having some issues with other things but that really solved my problems with respect to the UI Automation libraries